# How come there is a TypeError in my Python code?

Tags: python, oop, traceback

```
from celery.task import Task
class Decayer(Task):

    def calc_decay_value(self, x):
        y = (1.0/(2^x))
        return y

    def calc_decay_time(self, x):
        y  = 2^x
        return y

    def run(self, d, **kwargs):

        #do stuff.

        return 0


>>> decayer = tasks.Decayer(r)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanDecay.py", line 31, in <module>
    decayer = tasks.Decayer(r)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two errors

1) Your class doesn't have an `__init__` function. Either add one, or use this instead:

```
decayer = tasks.Decayer()
```

2) You are trying to raise an integer to the power of a float, but `^` means xor and cannot be used on floats. Use `**` instead of `^`:

```
y = 2 ** x
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems due to `decayer = tasks.Decayer(r)` call and tasks.Decayer is not designed to take a argument, because `Task` does not define a `__init__` method which can take one.